# Smoothly Move Buttons and Camera one by one in UI Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some advice regarding creation of UI Menu. Right now I've got several canvases representing different menus (Main, Options, NewGame etc.). Right now I'm using Vector3 and transform.position and rotation for the main camera to move around these canvases (menus). But it looks not very smooth.

I need the camera to kinda start moving a bit slower, then gain speed and when it approaches a new canvas to slowly lose speed (sort of a smooth movement).

As for the buttons, I need them to be replaced by other buttons. For example, I've got a New Game menu with the Single Game and Multiplayer buttons and when I hit Single Game, these two buttons must flip to the left and other buttons need to take their place in the same fashion.

So, the question is - what's the best way to acheive that? Is it better to do the whole thing in script or use animations triggered on click? Just point me in the right direction. What methods should be used? 
Just references will suffice, no coding needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a recommendation – use a single canvas. As for animations, look into DOTween.

Comment: @Iggy Can't use only one canvas, since the menu is an entire level with props etc. That's the whole idea

Comment: IMHO, using animations will lead to better results, but is if you decide to change the position of your menus or their layout, you will have to rework the animations. Using code is more flexible, but if you have many scripts, it may lag a little bit. @Iggy : using a single heavy canvas may not be the best solution since all the elements will be redrawn when one of the latters moves.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to check out new [unity 2017 timeline and cinemachine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1SkOoJJRAA).
Timeline will let you do any animation easily with your buttons and make them blend into each other for smoothness and a number of other effects, and they have anything you need for camera movements and its super easy.